# WPF - DataTemplate/Value Converter for hyperlink in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, hyperlink, ivalueconverter

I have a ListBox showing a list of people's names, emails, departments, etc. There is a DataTemplate that has a few TextBlocks to display each property. One of these TextBlocks is wrapping a Hyperlink to show email addresses like so:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Email}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" />
   </Hyperlink>   
</TextBlock>
```

This works fine, but if the person doesn't have an email address, the TextBlock is not collapsed automatically. So I wrote a value converter and used in the style like so (simplified):

```
string s = (String) value;
if (s == ""){
   return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
return Visibility.Visible;
```

And this is the Style using the ValueConverter:

```
<Style x:Key="ResultItemTextBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                                    Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

And I added the style calling the converter to the TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResultItemTextBoxStyle}">
   <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Email}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" />
   </Hyperlink>   
</TextBlock>
```

After this change the email address is never shown - In the value converter, the text of the TextBlock is always empty and it returns Visibility.Collapsed. It is like it's evaluating the text of the TextBlock before the Hyperlink get loaded or something...

Please help me figure this one out.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure email isn't null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter that you wrote is comparing the `Text` of the `TextBlock` to empty, not the text of the inner `Hyperlink`. I think you really want to set the `RelativeSource` to the child `Hyperlink`,  but I don't think that is possible.

Are you sure that it is the `TextBlock`'s size that doesn't get collapsed? If you put the style on the `Hyperlink` instead (or even its inner `TextBlock`), maybe that would still work?

Edit: `Hyperlink` doesn't have a `Visibility` property, so moving the style to it won't help, unfortunately. The only other option that I can think of is to create a custom control that derives from `TextBlock`, and it contains a `Hyperlink` and `TextBlock`. If you add an `Email` `DependencyProperty` to it, then you can use that to determine if the control should be visible or not, and for the value of the `Hyperlink` and its inner `TextBlock`.

It seems like there should be a better way to handle this, but I can't think of anything currently.

Comment: Andy, thanks. I had thought of that but, as you pointed out, it seems like there should be a more straight-forward solution.
I created a little user control and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Style>
      <Style>
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Email}" Value="">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBlock.Style>
   <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Email}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}" />
   </Hyperlink>   
</TextBlock>
```

I think writing a value converter is overkill (no offense intended).

Comment: Bob,
Thanks for your answer. It's not an offense at all. I agree that a converter for that is an overkill. But since I have have many other string properties that may be empty, I can use the converter everywhere.

I was excited to test your suggestions but it still shows me the same result - It doesn't collapse when email is empty. :(

Answer (score -1):

I know this is not exactly your question, but why do you use textblocks at all?

Simply using

```
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Email}" Content="{Binding Email}" 
Visibility="{Binding Email, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

should do what you want it do do, unless I am mistaken.

update: OK, I am mistaken, WPF Hyperlink is not Silverlight's HyperlinkButton and does not have a Content property. Shame on me.

Comment: That dosen't work for me. Hyperlink doesn't have a Content property, and it can't be added to its container directly because it isn't an UIElement.

Comment: Dammit, I was thinking about an HyperlinkButton, which exists in Silverlight, not WPF.

Sorry about that, I'll go to bed now...